# Javascript Parse JSON array get value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
        "searchResults": [
            {
                "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/689997",
                "id": 689997
            },
            {
                "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/691005",
                "id": 691005
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to get the value of "id": 691005

I thought I could do something like this:

```
    <script>
    var myJson = ({
        "searchResults": [
            {
                "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/689997",
                "id": 689997
            },
            {
                "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/691005",
                "id": 691005
            }
        ]
    })

    myArray = JSON.parse(myJson);
    console.log(myArray[1]);
</script>
```

throws an error.

How can I get the value "691005" from the data using only JS not libraries?

Comment: The thing you have posted it not JSON, it's an object. You can tell because the "an error" it throws tells you: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data". Also, why wrapping with  `()`?

Comment: `JSON.parse` stand for string content, and produce a JSON data. your `var myJson` is already a JSON data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` is used to produce a JSON from a string, not from another JSON.

Instead, simply get the `id` property from the second item in the `searchResults` property.

```js
const myJson = {
  "searchResults": [{
      "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/689997",
      "id": 689997
    },
    {
      "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/691005",
      "id": 691005
    }
  ]
}


const id = myJson.searchResults[1].id;
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also find the item by the id, instead of the index of the array, like that

```
var myJson = `
{
  "searchResults": [
      {
          "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/689997",
          "id": 689997
      },
      {
          "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/691005",
          "id": 691005
      }
  ]
}
`

const myArray = JSON.parse(myJson);
const selectedItem = myArray.searchResults.find((item) => {
  return item.id === 689997
});

console.log(selectedItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it directly:

```
<script>
    var myJson = ({
        "searchResults": [
            {
                "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/689997",
                "id": 689997
            },
            {
                "self": "https://api.icims.com/customers/xxxx/applicantworkflows/691005",
                "id": 691005
            }
        ]
    })

    console.log(myJson['searchResults'][0]['id']);

</script>
```

This code will output: 691005.